# R Shiny & ggplot- scale_fill_manual with reactive input?

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I'm trying to manually change the color of a ggplot with a reactive switch statement based on user input choosing the group to color by. I came up with a solution with a forloop because I was having a hard time with scale_fill_manual taking the output list from the reactive function. I couldn't find any examples on the shiny tutorials or question on forums regarding this issue with scale_fill_manual, so I'm wondering, is there a simpler way that I missed?

I tried to use scale_fill_manual(values=color_fill()), as well as assigning color_fill() outside the ggplot function, and then putting that object through scale_fill_manual [ (col = color_fill()) and then in ggplot call +scale_fill_manual(values = col) ) but it output errors with the switch statement. The only work around I found was a forloop through the object assigned from calling the reactive function, which seems really clunky to me.

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
data(warpbreaks)

ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("Wool Breaks"),
    
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
          varSelectInput("xvar", "Group by:", warpbreaks, selected = "wool"),
          selectInput("color", label="Color by:", choices = names(warpbreaks), selected= "tension")
        ),

        # Show a plot of the generated distribution
        mainPanel(
           plotOutput("distPlot"),
           textOutput("outputs")
        )
    )
)


server <- function(input, output) {
    color_fill = reactive({
      switch(input$color,
             "wool" = c("A"="#66C2A5", "B"="#FC8D62"),
             "tension" = c("L"="#d7191c","M"="#ffffbf","H"="#abdda4")
      )
    })
  
    output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
        cols = color_fill()
        col = color_fill()
        color<- list()
        for (i in 1:length(col)){
          color[[i]]=col[i]
          i = i+ 1
        }
        ggplot(warpbreaks, aes(y=breaks, x=!!input$xvar, fill=get(input$color)))+
          geom_boxplot() +
        scale_fill_manual(values=color)
     
    })
   
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

Substituting `scale_fill_manual(values=color_fill())` into your code appears to work for me:

```r
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
data(warpbreaks)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # Application title
  titlePanel("Wool Breaks"),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      varSelectInput("xvar", "Group by:", warpbreaks, selected = "wool"),
      selectInput("color", label="Color by:", choices = names(warpbreaks), selected= "tension")
    ),
    
    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("distPlot"),
      textOutput("outputs")
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output) {
  color_fill = reactive({
    switch(input$color,
           "wool" = c("A"="#66C2A5", "B"="#FC8D62"),
           "tension" = c("L"="#d7191c","M"="#ffffbf","H"="#abdda4")
    )
  })
  
  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(warpbreaks, aes(y=breaks, x=!!input$xvar, fill=get(input$color)))+
      geom_boxplot() +
      scale_fill_manual(values=color_fill())
    
  })
  
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
#> 
#> Listening on http://127.0.0.1:6254
```

[image]